# Getting data in an ember component from an API

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, components

I’m trying to create a Ember service that calls an API to query data in a database. I want to create this service so I can inject a dataset (an array of objects) in various controllers, components and routes. I’m not sure if this is one of ember’s ‘best practices’ but it seems like it will solve an immediate issue while learning the framework. For this example I have a service called ‘get-data.js’ and I have a component called ‘responsive-table.js’ that i want to have access to an array of objects that I receive from my database. Should I be using a service to make a ajax request to the api every time i need this array? Should I be using ‘ember-data’ and calling to the ‘store’ and use the ‘findAll’ method? Whenever I try to call to the store and comment out the response from a ‘findAll’ I get a class object? Whats the best way to access your server data in components and controllers with ember.js and ‘ember-data’

service

```
// service 

import Ember from 'ember';

const {
  Service, inject: { service }, computed, run, set, get
} = Ember;

export default Service.extend({
    ajax: service(),

    usingJQueryAjax() {
        let data = $.get('/api/data').then(function(result ) {
            console.log("right here: ", result );
            return result;
        });

        return data
    }

});
```

componet

```
// component 

import Ember from 'ember';

const {
  Component, inject, get, set, $
} = Ember;

export default Component.extend({
    store: inject.service(),

    actions: {
        usingStoreDoesntWork() {
            var data = get(this, 'store').findAll('nba');
            return data; 
        },

        usingJQueryAjax() {
            var data = $.getJSON('/api/data').then(function(result) {
                console.log("Array I want to return: ", result );
            });
            return data;
        }
    }
});
```

Whats the best approach to get data into a component from an API ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ember Components are designed to have no connection to a source of data.  This increases their reusability, since all data that a component uses must be passed in.

Typically, the bridge from your server application and the Ember model is the `Route`.  Here, you do what is necessary to retrieve data and return it in the `model()` hook.  This is true whether or not you use *Ember Data*.

Your route (which is configured in `router.js`), will be called when necessary to get a model.  Your template will have access to that via the variable `model`.  You would then include a component in your template and pass data to the model via attributes.

### Route

```
model() {
  // retrieve data here, using whatever technique you want.  It could be 
  // constant data or retrieved via jQuery, or the Ember Data mechanism (e.g.
  // the "store"
  return {
    someList: [1,2,3,4,5]
  };
}
```

### Template

```
Here's your data:
{{list-display list=model.someList}}
```

### Component template

```
<ul>
  {{#each list as |item|}}
    <li>{{item}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The component, `list-display` can now display any list, so it is nicely reusable.  The connection with data is made in the route template, and the data is retrieved by the `Route`.  If you want to create a `Service` to retrieve data, then use the service in the `Route` to return data from the `model()` hook.

Hope this clarifies it for you.

Comment: Steve, this is great! It actually confirms what I thought about how Ember wants me to access my data. what if I want to do some basic logic on my server-side data. would I do that in a 'serializer'? maybe in the model file? What's the best practice to perform basic logic on server-side data within an Ember App? thanks for your feedback!

Comment: When you say "logic", I'm not sure what you mean.  You might consider computed properties on your model if you need to derive some value from model properties: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/object-model/computed-properties/

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with computed properties and use them in some of my models currently. I think that building more complex models along with a serializer to isolate specific data I can probably accomplish what I'm looking to do. Until then I need more time reading guides. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction